# What if there exists no matched rule in a Lex program because of REJECT?

Tags: lex, lexical-analysis

I'm currently reading the documentation on Lex written by [Lesk and Schmidt](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/index.html), and get confused by the REJECT action.

Consider the two rules

```
a[bc]+   { ... ; REJECT;}
a[cd]+   { ... ; REJECT;}
```

Input:

```
ab
```

Only the first matches, and see what we get from the material.

> The action REJECT means ``go do the next alternative.'' It causes whatever rule was second choice after the current rule to be executed.

However, there is no second choice, will there comes a error?

Comment: I suspect - but I may be wrong - that lex will ultimately fall back on the implicit “echo unmatched characters to stdout” rule that’s always included.

Comment: @templatetypedef So there actually exists a hidden rule, my premise is wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are really very few use cases for `REJECT`; I don't think I've ever seen an instance of it in use other than in examples.

Anyway, unless you specify `%option nodefault` (or the `-s` command-line flag), flex will add a default fallback action to your ruleset, equivalent to

```
.|\n   ECHO;
```

In your case, that pattern will match after the REJECT.

However, it is possible to override the default action; for example, you could add the rule:

```
.|\n   REJECT;
```

In that case, flex really will not have an alternative after the two `REJECT`s, and it will print an error message on `stderr` ("flex scanner jammed") and then call `exit`.